# disable home button for API 19

Tags: android

I am working on one app(KIOSK). in that for API 19 following code is not working

```
 <activity android:name=".activity.HomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I want to set this app as launcher default app like home screen when user clicks on home button.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove: `<category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>`.

And you still need:

```
<activity ...>
   <!-- Add this -->
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
    <!-- Your other filter -->
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```